# VBA to Python conversion using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, excel, vba, beautifulsoup

[image: page source]

```
For Each hdiv In doc.getElementsByClassName("offset1 transport-plan location-detail well well-white margin20right")
                      For Each child In hdiv.Children
                         If child.tagName = "H4" Then
                            location = child.innerText    
                        ElseIf child.tagName = "TABLE" Then
                          If row.tagName = "TBODY" Then
                            For Each row1 In row.Children
                               do something

                           If row1.tagName = "TR" Then
                                For Each row2 In row1.Children
                                  If row2.innerText <> "" Then
                                    activity = row2.innerText
```

How can convert this VBA code into Python using Beautifulsoup

Only want to understand how to build child relationship

i was trying something like below

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for each_div in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "offset1 transport-plan location-detail well well-white margin20right" }):
    children = each_div.findChildren()
    for child in children:
        if child.name == "H4":
            print(child.text)

        elif child.name == "TABLE":
            print (child.text)
```

Comment: do you get error message (Traceback) ? show it in question (not in comment). What is page source ? Maybe problem is with source HTML, not with BS.

Comment: i am not getting any error its not entering to the first if condition i have writen - if child.name == 'H4':

Comment: standard method - use `print()` to see what you have in variable - `print(child.name)`. I expect you have `h4`, not `H4`.

Comment: you can check the complete source attached in image

Comment: yup i did the print immediately after - for child in children: print(child.text), this is giving me the complete text inside DIV class

Comment: I mean check `print(child.name)`